# How to load data from two different SQL tables into a Single workbook in two different sheets using SSIS or Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am trying to load the data from from two different SQL tables into a Single workbook in two different sheets using SSIS or Azure Data Factory.

I found excel can't be used as Destination in case of Azure datafactory and there is no workaround.

So, I thought Can we perform this action using SSIS?

Requirement is -

I have two tables Say TableA and TableB.

I want to load the data of TableA into Sheet1 of a Excel workbook (Book1) and  TableB into Sheet2 of same Excel workbook (Book1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this in SSIS, these are, roughly, the steps:

1. Create the workbook, with the 2 sheets and their corresponding columns
2. In SSIS create 2 data flows to run in sequence
3. In the first data flow select an OleDB source and point it to the Table A
4. Create an excel destination and point to the created spreadsheet/Sheet1
5. Connect the OleDB source to the Excel source and map the columns
6. Repeat 2 to 5 for the other data flow but using TableB and created spreadsheet/Sheet2